# sibling floats to bottom when $(this) height increases

Tags: css

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="inlined">
        <div>first-child</div>
        <div>last-child</div> 
    </div>        

    <div class="inlined">
        <div>first-child-1</div>
        <div>last-child-1</div> 
    </div>        

</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

`.inlined div:last-child` is hidden, when it is shown, it's parent `div .inlined` gains height. then the `div .inlined` next to it moves to the bottom of wrapper.

i want it to stick to the top.

i have many `div .inlined` elements, 2 in a row

http://jsfiddle.net/C3v2k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vertical alignment to `.inlined`

```
.inlined
{
    vertical-align:top;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/C3v2k/1/

Comment: great, you saved the world today.